# Protect the form definition yaml from being overwritten

Tags: forms, typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I'm working on a legacy page with TYPO3 9.5

I made a form and heavily edited the form'S YAML file. I especially added YAML aliases.
When I now edit the form in the TYPO3 BE form editor and save it, the anchors and aliases are lost.

**Is there a way that I can protect parts or the whole of my YAML definition to be not touched by the TYPO3 BE form editor on save?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible - check the documentation about that at https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/main/en-us/I/Concepts/FormFileStorages/Index.html

As this change has been implemented with 8.7 (see [here](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/8.6/Feature-79250-ExtFormExtendExtensionLocationFunctionality.html)) it will also work on 9.5

```yaml
TYPO3:
     CMS:
       Form:
         persistenceManager:
           allowSaveToExtensionPaths: false
           allowedExtensionPaths:
             100: EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Forms/
```

Comment: Thank's a lot. As I see, this is on a global scale and work for all Forms. Isn't there a way to define it on a per form basis?

Comment: IMO no, but that could be easily solved with some xclassing